# Laravel - How to update field value in sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

On my `laravel` project, I created the following record in `sqlite` using `php artisan tinker`.

```
   App\Note {#642
     id: "1",
     card_id: "2",
     body: "Some note for the card",
     created_at: "2016-06-19 22:18:34",
     updated_at: "2016-06-19 22:18:34",
   }
```

How can I change the `card_id` field to 1 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$note = App\Note::find(1);
$note->card_id = '1';
$note->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Note` model to update the `card_id` value.

```
$note = Note::find(1);
$note->update([
    'card_id' => '1',
]);
```